# When using the new WebApplicationFactory and resulting CreateClient, is there a way to get routes without using strings?

Tags: c#, testing, asp.net-core, integration-testing, asp.net-core-2.1

I have code like the following:

```c#
public class SmokeTests : IClassFixture<CustomConfigurationWebApplicationFactory<MyApplication.API.Startup>>
{
    private readonly CustomConfigurationWebApplicationFactory<MyApplication.API.Startup> _factory;

    private const string urlPrefix = "/api/";

    public SmokeTests(CustomConfigurationWebApplicationFactory<MyApplication.API.Startup> factory)
    {
        _factory = factory;
    }

    [Theory]
    [InlineData(ControllerName.Contact)] 
    [InlineData(ControllerName.Location)] // This essentially is: `public const string Contact = nameof(Contact);`
    [InlineData("LifecycleMaturitie")]
    public async Task Get_EndpointsReturn_SuccessfulCode_CorrectContentType_SomeData(string controllerName)
    {
        // Arrange
        var client = _factory.CreateClient();

        // Act
        var response = await client.GetAsync($"{urlPrefix}{controllerName}s/1");

        // Assert
        var json = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
        var dyn = JObject.Parse(json);

        response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode(); // Status Code 200-299
        Assert.Equal("application/json; charset=utf-8",
            response.Content.Headers.ContentType.ToString());
        Assert.Equal(1, dyn["Id"]);
    }
}
```

I know this is bad code for multiple reasons. the biggest is this nasty thing `$"{urlPrefix}{controllerName}s/1"` what I want to be able to do is create a route using strongly typed code like `nameof`. I looked into UrlHelper in core 2.1 but it requires an action context. I am assuming since the core team created all this WebApplicationFactory stuff they have also ran across this same problem.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, no. Getting the route requires a `UrlHelper` instance, which you cannot retrieve outside the context of a request pipeline.

That said, the route is a contract and as such is something that deserves to be tested in its own right. If the route your test is using changes, the test *should* fail, to indicate that that contract has been broken. What I tend to do is simply make my routes constants on my test class, and refer to them via those constants only. Then, if I do need to make a change, I only need to change it in one place.

FWIW, if I have a route that takes something like an id, I'll set the route like:

```
private const string FooRoute = "/foo/{0}";
```

Then, you can use`string.Format` when making the request:

```
await _client.GetAsync(string.Format(FooRoute, fooId));
```

Comment: Just implemented this, seems to work pretty well. Thanks.